# Default gateway not responding to pings with a TTL of 1

Tags: networking, router, ping, traceroute

<sub>I am attempting to create a `traceroute` program, but this isn't directly related to programming.</sub>

I noticed that my router will not respond with a Time Exceeded to pings that have a TTL of 1, which is problematic because that means that I can't "trace" it.

If I ping past my router (to a Google server for example) with a TTL of anything greater than 1, the next hops respond with a Time Exceeded as expected. If I try to ping past it with a TTL of 1 though, I don't get any reply at all; no ping reply, and no Time Exceeded response:

[image: Ping Discarded]

Is this expected behavior? My expectation is that the router should receive the packet that has a TTL of 1, decrement the TTL to 0, and that should trigger a Time Exceeded reply to be sent back. I want to know if this is typical behavior to ensure that this is the "fault" of the router, and not a fault in my understanding.

I don't have the ability to introduce another router into the network at the moment to test whether this is a quirk of my specific router or not.

For anyone familiar with Scapy, this illustrates the problem:

```
# No response. Times out and returns nothing.
sr1(IP(dst="google.com", ttl=1) / ICMP(), timeout=5)  

# Returns a Time Exceeded immediately from the next hop past my router.
sr1(IP(dst="google.com", ttl=2) / ICMP(), timeout=5)
```

The router is an Asus RT-AC1750

---

<sub>This seems like it would be more appropriate on Network Engineering, but they appear to have a *hard* requirement that your question has nothing to do with home networks, and it would have been obvious that I'm on a home network as soon as they started asking any questions. Reading over their Meta, Super User appears to be where home-networking-type questions are appropriate.</sub>

Comment: This is a bug in your router's firmware. Load OpenWrt or Merlin and see if it behaves better.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks. I realized after that I should be handling this case anyways, but it's good to know that it's my router that's in the wrong.